# jQuery sliders calculator

Tags: jquery, sliders

Hi I want to create some sliders, what i need to do is to make a slider which has 3 options in it:

1. the amount the user wants to borrow (from 12,500 upto 100,000) - will display a value from where the selector is here
2. over how long (from five yrs upto 25yrs) - will display a value from where the selector is here
3. Estimate based on the values the monthly repayment.

i have looked at others on here but don't quite understand how they work logically so if anyone could help would be great.

I have added a quick image i made to dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12506430/sliders.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8aesb/).

```
<h2>How much would you like to borrow?</h2>
<div id="amount"></div>

<h2>Over how long?</h2>
<div id="period"></div>

<h2>Result</h2>
Your monthly payment will be $<span id="monthly">204.86</span>


function update() {
    var amount = $('#amount').slider('value');
    var period = $('#period').slider('value');
    var monthly = (amount + amount * 0.03 * period) / (period * 12);
    $("#monthly").text(monthly.toFixed(2));

}

$("#amount").slider({
    value: 12500,
    min: 12500,
    max: 100000,
    step: 50,
    slide: function() {
        update();
    }
});

$("#period").slider({
    value: 5,
    min: 5,
    max: 25,
    step: 1,
    slide: function() {
        update();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for that but i also need to show the current sliders amount for both:


`$('#amount').slider('value');
    $('#period').slider('value');`


as per the slider image to the right of each slider, but am unsure how to do it?

thanks.

Comment: Here is an update to display the current values: http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/wT7pF/

Comment: thanks for doing that but unfortunately i need a bit more and this is where it gets quite complex: I have a spreadsheet: `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12506430/LOAN%20CALC%20FIGURES.xlsx` so there are three sheets
clean, middle and adverse
I want that dependant on the credit rating it uses 1 of 3 sheets
so if its good it uses the clean sheet
and if you move the amount and years it would then get the data from this sheet, its immensely complex.

Comment: In that case you should change the `update` function and instead of having a single `monthly = formula` you have to put in a `if ... else` or a `switch ... case` and use the appropriate formula and/or coefficient for calculation of monthly paybacks.

Comment: would you be able to do it for me, I don't know enough jquery to do that as there is lots of data.